# I Can't Run npm run script its showing many errors

Tags: html, css, npm, sass, command-prompt

I tried many times to run npm script I also added the script in the `package.json` file but its showing some errors actually I am building a website and I needed npm sass to make it but the npm run `compile:sass` which is my script is showing errors here's the image which is facing the problem.

Here's the script code:

```
{  
   "name":"natours",
   "version":"1.0.0",
   "description":"landing page for natours",
   "main":"index.js",
   "scripts":{  
      "compile:sass":"node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css"        <=====
   },
   "author":"Kishan",
   "license":"ISC",
   "devDependencies":{  
      "node-sass":"^4.9.0"
   }
}
```

And here's the error in command prompt:

```
C:\Users\ANONYMOUS>npm run compile:sass
npm ERR! path C:\Users\ANONYMOUS\package.json 
npm ERR! code ENOENT 
npm ERR! errno -4058 
npm ERR! syscall open 
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\ANONYMOUS\package.json' 
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file. 
npm ERR! enoent 
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: 
npm ERR! C:\Users\ANONYMOUS\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-06-17T05_39_21_109Z-debug.log C:\Users\ANONYMOUS>
```

Comment: Have you saved this json file as `package.json` and run the `compile:saas` from the location `package.json` sits?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a comma between node-sass sass/main.scss and css/style.css

it should be node-sass sass/main.scss, css/style.css

Comment: The [usage](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#usage-1) docs indicate that a comma in _NOT_ necessary between <input> and <output> paths.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is with locating the file, not the formatting of the file or the content that error should be thrown later if necessary.

Are you sure that your package.json is in the folder you are running the command from? Try the "dir" console command in the shell where you are executing "npm start" to check if it is.

Also, depending on what editor you are using I used to make a mistake when I started programming of saving files with the wrong format especially something like package.json.txt if using notepad.